# What's the difference between an Asset and a Resource?

Tags: terminology, resources

I've used several IDEs and created several default projects. Upon creation, I'll find folder structures created for me. Sometimes I'll see a Resources folder, sometimes an Assets folder, and sometimes both. Is there actually a (standard) difference?

Answer (score 21):

Most of the time I would consider them synonyms. They both serve as valid places to store non-source code items.

When both appear in the same project, the only difference I can come up with

- Resource - Configuration files, something that has code or markup in it
- Asset - Images, video, other things that aren't code, markup, or configuration. Think very static

I will say though that the difference is minor and outside of a few circumstances they should be considered synonyms.

Comment: In Unity custom C# scripts is in an assets folder if I'm not mistaking. So the difference depend on who you're asking.

Comment: Resource can be also raw materials...

Answer (score 5):

It's a just a difference in terminology.  In this context assets are the non-source code resources you use in your solution.

We follow a /res/ name convention, which typically stores javascript, css, images, and more.  Javascript and CSS are source code resources, so assets is more concerned with media (images, video, documents) etc. a subset of resources, if you will.

Comment: What about in the context of a video game? You might attach an image to a "GameComponent" as a Sprite. Now, it's being used in your solution, but it's still static content. What should it be called?

Answer (score -2):

I found the php framework -- Laravel use `resources` folder as front-end folder. `assets` as subsets of `resources` to store the source code of js and css.